# bf-ecb encrypt with openssl the same way as in Java

Tags: java, openssl

An encryption is done in a legacy Java system as :

```
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("Blowfish/ECB/NoPadding");
cipher.init(1, new SecretKeySpec(theKey.getBytes(), "BlowFish"));
byte[] arrayOfByte = cipher.doFinal(inputString.getBytes());
String result = new BASE64Encoder().encode(arrayOfByte);
```

I am trying to replicate it with openssl, but I don't get the same output.

I am trying:

```
openssl enc -base64 -A -bf-ecb -nosalt -in input -pass pass:secret
```